# Horizontally scroll to an element inside another element

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, scroll, overflow

In Firefox, you can easily horizontally scroll to an element inside another element via the `scrollTo()` function:

```
var el=$("#element");
var x=el.position().left-el.width();
$("#container").get(0).scrollTo(x,0);
```

But in Chrome, that fails. Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/o9wgufq2/

Is there a cross-browser way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first thing, please enclose your attributes in HTML with double quotes, ie. class="c" not class=c

jQuery scrollTo is a plugin so if you are looking to use it then you need to load up the plugin. but the shipped methods scrollLeft and scrollTop are enough to achieve your goal here.

```
var el=$(".c .d4");
var x=el.position().left-el.width();
$(".c").eq(0).scrollLeft(x);
```

Note, I have changed the get(0) with eq(0) to get the equivalent index 0 of of .c elements.

Here is an updated fiddle of your fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/o9wgufq2/5/

Comment: Awesome! scrollLeft() is the solution.